# SEVERE: No message body writer has been found for class java.util.Vector, ContentType: application/xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

I have a minimal JAX-RS application.  I am trying to produce an XML response, but instead I get the exception below. The resource should return a List of Country objects, but the exception refers to a Vector. I am running TomEE Web Profile 9.0.0-M7 and Jakarta Web Profile 9.1.

**Exception**

```
Mar 04, 2022 12:33:42 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils logMessageHandlerProblem
SEVERE: No message body writer has been found for class java.util.Vector, ContentType: application/xml
```

**Application**

```
import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
}
```

**Country Resource**

```
@Path("/country")
public class CountryResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        return Database.get().findCountries();
    }
}
```

**Country query**

```
public List<Country> findCountries() {
    return em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Country c ORDER BY c.countryName", Country.class).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Does the class `Country` use a `Vector`? Maybe show its definition, too ...

Comment: XML needs a single root element. By specifying that the return type is `List<Country>` you would get a root element per list element. Create a wrapper class that contains a `List<Country> countries`, then return that. You can do the wrapping in your `CountryResource`.

Comment: Thanks! That resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Country needs to be annotated with an XmlRootElement annotation.